# How to create gradient text for UITextfield's Text

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I want this effect (show in below image link) with UITextfield text and if there is any IOS library available then suggest me and only for UITextfield not for UILabel

Link:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIliK.jpg

Comment: Take look at this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904908/uilabel-text-color-based-on-custom-linear-gradient

Comment: I already tried it and it's for UILabel