# UISegmentedControl tintColor gradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to set the foreground/tintColor of a UISegmentedControl to a horizontal gradient.  I want the gradient to extend across the control and appropriately adjust when each segment is clicked. See image below:

[image: Desired UISegmentedControl gradient]

I've tried setting the tintColor using the stackoverflow solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19368096/6543020), but using colorWithPattern doesn't seem to work when I change it to be horizontal:

[image]

Here's what I'm using now:

```
UIView* test2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 200, 25)];
test2.backgroundColor = [self gradientFromColor:[UIColor redColor] toColor:[UIColor greenColor] withWidth:test2.frame.size.width];
[self.view addSubview:test2];

UISegmentedControl *test = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"one", @"two"]];
test.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 25);
test.tintColor = [self gradientFromColor:[UIColor redColor] toColor:[UIColor greenColor] withWidth:test.frame.size.width];
[self.view addSubview:test];
```

...

```
- (UIColor*) gradientFromColor:(UIColor*)c1 toColor:(UIColor*)c2 withWidth:(int)width{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, 1);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 1);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    NSArray* colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)c1.CGColor, (id)c2.CGColor, nil];
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace, (CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(width, 0), 0);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
}
```

I'm thinking I need to do some work with masking but I've been having trouble getting it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure if gradient color could work with tint color. Probably it would be simpler to use custom buttons with custom background images instead of your segmented control.

Comment: That's what I've been using in the meantime, but I'm hoping to have a couple different sizes so it's annoying to make all the custom images so it doesn't stretch poorly.  That certainly is a workaround though.

Comment: It's really interesting and I hope you find a solution, but now it looks like not a problem with gradient, but like a problem with tint color.